Referencing values from an undefined number of sheets in Numbers
I'm trying to create a simple personal budget spreadsheet in Numbers. I want a front page sheet showing a chart of some value over the X latest months. The months themselves are represented by sheets "2024-11", "2024-12", "2025-01", and so on. I intend on creating a new sheet every month, and thus I want to track how well I've held my budget over the past year by showing these values in the chart.
Is it possible to do this?
I've tried some of the more simple commands available in Numbers and am familiar with how to reference other sheets, tables and cells. The problems I face when doing this is making a formula that "automatically increases" the number of sheets it considers, whenever a new sheet is created.

Welcome to Ask Different :) Consider editing your question to mention what have you tried so far or what hurdles (if any) you are facing when trying to accomplish this.
